# Hide file extension and php get variables in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, strtok

I have URL like this :

```
http://domain.net/news.php?url=/abcd.html
```

I need strip ***.php?url=*** to URL like this:

```
http://domain.net/news/abcd.html
```

Just tried :

1. Modify .htaccess file : `RewriteRule ^news/(.*) news.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`
2. Put strtok in news.php :

   $url=strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');

But it not work, in root folder, Drupal CMS running, that mean file index.php handle everything.

My .htaccess file here : http://pastebin.com/xktzt0yc

Please help!

Comment: have you defined RewriteLog ?

Comment: @MTroy : i don't know exactly what you mean but rewrite url working fine on my server.

Comment: yes i know, i proposed rewritelog for the root. May be this doc can help you ? https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls (about rewritebase)
what is your drupal version ?

Comment: Clean URL for Drupal just working fine, i just need clean url for news.php script (news.php is not Drupal script, just running same folder with Drupal)

Comment: Please show your entire .htaccess codes including Drupal rewrite. The order matters.

Comment: @PanamaJack : Here : https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/6.x/.htaccess

Comment: I wasn't asking for the default drupal code. I wanted to see yours. Where did you put this rule for news. At the top or bottom? show your .htaccess file and add it to the question.

Comment: @PanamaJack : http://pastebin.com/xktzt0yc

Comment: Edit the question and post it there please.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your pattern and substitute is mixed. Have you tried to switch the pattern and substitute?

```
RewriteRule news.php?url=(.*) ^news/$1 [L,QSA]
```